# Event Listener for hidden from true to false?

Tags: events, reactjs, hidden

I am trying to add a listener in a react project such that if a div (attribute hidden) goes from hidden = true to hidden = false, the event would fire. Is this possible to do?

Comment: is this attribute on a react component you created?

Comment: It feels like you're approaching this backwards. In React, your app state should drive DOM changes, not the other way around. What's causing this div to toggle between hidden and visible?